# How can one ensure that the style guide is maintained and used?

Tags: business, style-guide

How can one ensure that the style guide is maintained and used?

I'm specifically working with UX styleguides.

Comment: If you're applying for a designer role in this position you should probably be the one giving the answer, not asking...

Comment: Don't know if you noticed, first answer is mine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to keep a style guide up to date and widely used in the organisation is to make it as a **Living style guide**, following a **Styleguide Driven Development** approach in the product development process.

Here are a few definitions of those two terms:

**Living style guide** definitions:

> “A design showcase built using live presentation codebase.”
>   — *Chris LoPresto* at [EmberConf 2016 ▶️ [7'00"]](https://youtu.be/Z1lL_Zo62h0?t=420)
>
> “A reference for a team of designers and developers to understand how an application will look and feel.”
>   — *Patrick Hildebrandt* in [What Is a Living Style Guide?](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/what-is-a-living-style-guide)
>
> “A living document of code, which details all the various elements and coded modules of your site or application.”
>   — *Susan Robertson* in [Creating Style Guides](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-style-guides)
>
> “A live version of a brand style guide.”
>   “Living style guides are something that should be developed with every project”
>   — *Brian Eye* in [Night of the Living Style Guide](https://keyholesoftware.com/2015/07/20/living-style-guide/)
>
> “An important tool for web development today, especially in large, complex web applications.”
>   — *Steven Lambert* in [Creating A Living Style Guide: A Case Study](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/creating-a-living-style-guide-case-study/)
>
> “A documentation of UI elements and patterns collected from a site or application with the purpose to allow developers to use consistent styles across their whole project.”
>   — *Nancy Young* in [Ten Living Style Guide Tools for Web Designers – Best of](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-living-style-guide-tools/)

**Styleguide Driven Development** definitions:

> “Is the practice of using the styleguide as the focal point for all front-end UI development tasks”
>   — *Matt Fordham* in [Styleguide Driven Development](https://speakerdeck.com/mattfordham/styleguide-driven-development?slide=9) at [Seattle Interactive Conference 2014](http://www.seattleinteractive.com/)
>
> “A practice that encourages the separation of UX, Design & Frontend from Backend concerns. This is achieved by developing the UI separately in a styleguide.”
>   — *Jordan Lewis* in [We build Envato: Styleguide Driven Development](https://webuild.envato.com/blog/styleguide-driven-development/)

If you need to go deeper on how to implement a *Styleguide Driven Development* process in your organisation, a simple [search on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Styleguide+Driven+Development) will bring you a few good presentations.

To finish, a very good example of style guide that implements these concepts is the [lonely planet style guide](http://rizzo.lonelyplanet.com/). They even wrote a very good article about why and how they built it: [A Maintainable Style Guide](http://engineering.lonelyplanet.com/2014/05/18/a-maintainable-styleguide.html)

Answer (score -2):

To be maintained a style guide needs to be online as a blog or a wiki. To be used a style guide must be based on principles rather than on rules to be a guide and not a break.

Comment: …with copious examples or those with access to the design elements but no graphic sense, or mis-placed egos, or desire for self-expression will get it wrong. You need to limit the editing access to a wiki-based style guide or "compass."